# How to make a react component persistent across many pages in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I may have worded the question wrongly, I don't know how to put what I want to do in a simple statement. [image]

At the right hand side of the attached image there is a red-colour message icon or component. This icon or component remains in the same location across most of the pages that the user navigates. It disappears only when the user clicks on it, in which case, it redirects the user to a chatroom. How do I use react to accomplish something like this? What is this called? I have difficulty searching how to do it on the internet because I don't even know what it is called. I can add such an icon or component manually on each of my webpage, but that seems to be too stressful. That Icon or component is situated at the same location regardless of the page being navigated

Comment: your image link isn't working...But why don't you make that icon a component and add manual stylings such as `position: absolute` so that it stays in the same position in all pages

Comment: That picture I posted is not from my webpage. I got it from a website on the internet because it has what I'm trying to implement. I used the picture so that it will enable me to explain what I want to achieve

Comment: Typically, there are `Header` and `Footer` components that may be used. And the actual UI elements will be between these two. In your case, may be you can explore having a footer component which gets rendered at the top-level (such as App.js or home-page, etc).

Comment: just like this in this app: https://demos.creative-tim.com/material-dashboard-react/?_ga=2.114596999.18163013.1649652063-1613949843.1643112305#/dashboard you can download code from [here](https://www.creative-tim.com/product/material-dashboard-react)

Comment: The thing is called "floating action button"

Comment: Thanks so much @M Usama. Please this to the answer section

Comment: You need to share some code/structure which you have done so far. Otherwise, all answers will be based on assumptions and cannot clearly help you out @C-Bizz